# How to split example data table into BCNF/4NF?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm trying to get more of a grasp on simple database concepts and am having trouble on the higher normalizations. For instance, what would the following look like in Boyce Codd Normal Form (BCNF) & in 4th Normal Form (4NF)?

INVOICE(CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName, Phone, InvoiceNumber, DateIn, DateOut, ItemType, Quanitty, ItemPrice, ExtendedPrice, SpecialInstructions)

I did this so far, but I know I'm not quite there yet:

**CUSTOMER(CustomerNumber, FirstName, LastName, Phone, InvoiceNumber)
INVOICE(InvoiceNumber, DateIn, DateOut, ItemType, Quantity, ItemPrice, SpecialInstructions)**

According to the book I am reading, the following assumptions are already in place:

1. CustomerNumber --> (FirstName, LastName), but not CustomerNumber
   -->--> (FirstName, LastName)
2. CustomerNumber -->--> Phone. There may be more than one phone number for
   each customer.
3. One CUSTOMER has many ORDERS, but each ORDER is associated with only
   one CUSTOMER.
4. One ORDER has many ItemTypes, but each ItemType occurs only once in
   any ORDER.
5. Item price does not vary from order to order, so ItemType determines
   ItemPrice.
6. SpecialInstructions is associated with each item type, since
   different instructions may be given for different items.
7. Order number is a number assigned to the orders themselves, without
   association with any particular customer. Thus we have such numbers
   as “123454”, 123455”, etc, rather than “Customer 101, Order 1”,
   Customer 101, Order 2”, Customer 102, Order 1”, etc.
8. ItemPrice can vary with order so that special pricing offers are
   reflected in the price.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This probably belongs on [dba.se].  Just for starters, `INVOICE` should have a FK to `Customer`, not the other way around as you have it.

Comment: Can you show me how it should look 4NF?

Comment: Items shouldn't be in the Invoice table but rather in an InvoiceItems table. You're assuming that an invoice can only contain one item.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how to respond to this post ([see this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework/18244#18244)) so rather than an "answer" I'll just throw out a few ideas that will hopefully get you going in the right direction.

@Analytic, it looks like you've only worked through item #2! Where's your ORDER table?  What about ITEM?  Please add that to your post so that we know what your first attempts are (we're not going to do your homework for you!).

So since you've only given us your efforts on #1 and #2, I'll comment on the customer phone number.  Your design only allows for one phone number per customer so that doesn't meet the requirement right?  What data structure would you imagine could allow you to have multiple phone numbers for one customer?  Would you create more fields on the customer table like Phone1, Phone2, Phone3 etc.?  Would that be practical?  How many would you put?  What if a customer ever had more than you had planned for?  Check out this webpage describing [one-to-many](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/)) relationships.

If you want to add more of your work to this post and given it sincere effort we'll try to help you out.

Good luck.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for covering what you have! I'll take a fresh look into things in the morning and comment back on my progress.